# Rename the name of files in a folder with the help of Python Script, using name map from Excel sheet

Tags: python, xlrd

There are many CSV files in a folder which I want to renamed. There is an excel sheet which contains name of files to be renamed to folder.

The files in folder are named as

TestData_30April.csv

TestData_20April.csv

TestData_18April.csv etc

while the excel sheet contains the name as

0.25-TestData_30April

0.98-TestData_20April

0.33-TestData_20April etc

My Aim is to rename

"TestData_30April.csv" to "0.25-TestData_30April.csv" similarly for all other files as well.

Here is the Code that I wrote (which does not work as expected)

```
import os

import xlrd

#Excel Sheet containing name of files to be renamed in that folder

path="C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Test_Data\\Test_Summary.xlsx"

#Folder Containg all orginal file names

dir = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Wear_Data"

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path) 

sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

#In excel sheet column X or col_values(23) contains the file name to be renamed

print(sheet.col_values(23))  

list_of_filename_in_folder = [] # name of the files in the folder

list_of_filename_in_excel = [] #name of the files in excel

path_to_folder = ''  # base path of folder  

for name in list_of_filename_in_excel:

    excel_file_name = os.path.join(path_to_folder, name,'.csv')

    dir_file_name = os.path.join(path_to_folder,name.split('-')[1],'.csv' )

    if os.path.exists(dir_file_name):

      print('changing file name {} to {}'.format(name.split('-')[1],name))

      os.rename(dir_file_name, excel_file_name)

    else:

      print('no file {} with name found in location'.format(name.split('-')[1]+'.csv')
```

Comment: Can you please format your code part?

Comment: Are you facing a specific error? What does not work?

Comment: When i run the script the file name in the folder are not renamed.

Comment: do you get any error message ? always put full error message (full Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: dir_file_name = os.path.join(path_to_folder,name.split('-')[1],'.csv')

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: read my comment again: put error always in question - it will be more readable - and put FULL error - starting at word `Traceback`

Comment: you have error with index so check `print( name.split('-') )` before you use `[1]` - it seems you get list with one element but you try to get second element.

Comment: if you get errors then it is good to use `print()` to check values in variables. OR learn how to use debuger.

Comment: code is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit2:
as per excel file sample, try the following code:

```
import os 
with open('myfile.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    buff = f.read()

buff = buff.splitlines()[1:]

for data in buff:
    data = data.split(',')
    old_name, new_name = data[21] + '.csv', data[23] + '.csv'

    if os.path.exists(old_name):
        print('changing file name {} to {}'.format(old_name,new_name))
        os.rename(old_name, new_name)
    else:
        print('no file {} with name found in location'.format(old_name))
```

old answer

Edit:
the contents of file "myfile.csv" in below example are:

```
0.25-TestData_30April
0.98-TestData_20April
0.33-TestData_20April
```

in case you have problem reading your file, first make sure it is an csv formated file and you can open it in any text editor, if you still have problem you can try to open it with encoding='utf-8':

```
with open('myfile.csv', , encoding='utf-8') as f:
        file_names = f.read().split()
```

you can try this simple code based on your excel file is a csv file

```
import os

with open('myfile.csv') as f:
    file_names = f.read().split()

for name in file_names:
    new_name = name + '.csv'
    old_name = name.split('-')[-1] + '.csv'
    if os.path.exists(old_name):
        print('changing file name {} to {}'.format(old_name,new_name))
        os.rename(old_name, new_name)
    else:
        print('no file {} with name found in location'.format(old_name))
```

Tested output:

```
changing file name TestData_30April.csv to 0.25-TestData_30April.csv
no file TestData_20April.csv with name found in location
no file TestData_20April.csv with name found in location
```

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 700: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @PriyankaMishra make sure your excel file containing the new names is a csv format, if so, use `encoding='utf-8'` in open(), i.e. `with open('myfile.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:`

Comment: Sir,no file TestData_20April.csv with name found in location

Comment: Sir, The excel sheet contains some data from Column A to P but column-X contains file name to be renamed to that folder

Comment: Is your excel file a csv file? What is the extension or type of your excel file?

Comment: The excel sheet is a csv file with extension ".csv"

Comment: Can you open it in text editor like notepad and copy contents and paste it in your question above

Comment: "Can you open it in text editor like notepad " What shall i open in notepad??

Comment: Your excel sheet containing the file names, if you are on windows you can open notepad then drag your excel file ontop of notepad or you can right click and open with then choose notepad

Comment: Is it necessary to open in Notepad and paste it here. Is there any alternate way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193232/discussion-between-priyanka-mishra-and-mahmoud-elshahat).

Comment: @PriyankaMishra check edited code on top of my answer